# API for practicing file uploads

Tags: reactjs, axios, form-data

I am learning how to use axios and FormData object to upload files and make post requests in React. Is there an API I can use to practice file uploads and downloads?

Answer (score 0):

the typical dataformat for sending files is **[Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)**.

First there is need a place for hold that files - so i suggest useStateHook:

```
  const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([]);
```

Also in the most detailed acceptance criteria there can be a need for restrict and precise available formats:

```
  const acceptedImageFileType = [
      "image/jpeg",
      "image/jpg",
      "image/png",
      "image/gif",
    ];
    const acceptedVideoFileType = [
      "video/mp4",
      "video/mov",
      "video/avi",
      "video/quicktime"
    ];
```

---

But finally the question - for sending the data to API:

Create FormData()

```
const formData = new FormData();
```

Iterate per selected files (if there is multiple files then iterate - if no - there is one liner.

For multiple:

```
for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
  formData.append("Files", selectedFiles[i].File);
}
```

For one:

```
formData.append("Files", selectedFiles[0].File);
```

And next standard API Call ( based on your architecture for data transfer layer and backend URL)

```
axios.post(`endpointURL`, { formData })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.data);
  })
```